# Possible Android hotspot interface names

Tags: android, android-networking

Is there any way to get the name of the interface working for WiFi hotspot?
I have seen that there are many names e.x `ap0`, `swlan0` etc.

Anybody knows other names or a way to find it easily?

Answer (score -1):

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Network[] allNetworks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
for (Network network : allNetworks) {
    LinkProperties linkProperties = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(network);
    Log.i("Interface: ", linkProperties.getInterfaceName());
}
```

Check if this works for you, it returns values like "wlan0" or "radio0" for every possible network interface (including wifi).

Comment: I know how to list interfaces, but how to know which une is used for `WiFi Hotspot`? And what's their possible names on different devices...?!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).